# How to align text in a longtable column that has fixed column widths to the right?

Tags: align, longtable, columns, textwidth

How do I align the text that I have in the last column to the right? I checked several similar questions and they all use `tabularx`. However, I wish to use `longtable`only since my table spans multiple pages. I tried to use `r{0.15\textwidth}` in the code below instead of `p`, which does the job but throws a compilation error at the same time. Please help! Thanks

```
\begin{longtable}[H]{p{0.07\textwidth}  p{0.78\textwidth} p{0.15\textwidth}}
                \toprule
                &  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\# of firm-years}  \\
                \midrule
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: BTW, longtable does not support [H], just [l/c/r] (left/center/right].  OTOH, it ALWAYS acts like [H] (more or less).

Comment: Thanks @John Kormlyo

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new column as

```
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
```

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{6cm}}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{Rp{8cm}}\toprule
 col1 & col2 \\\midrule
 \lipsum[1] & \lipsum[2]  \\ \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with short entries instead of paragraphs, just make one entry wide enough using `\makebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\newlength{\tablewidth}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tablewidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth - 6\tabcolsep}% avaiable space for table entries
\begin{longtable}{p{0.07\tablewidth}  p{0.78\tablewidth} r}
                \toprule
                &  & \makebox[0.15\tablewidth][r]{\# of firm-years}  \\
                \midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```